# realmd join AD and Cross Domain Auth

Tags: active-directory, kerberos

Small issue with realmd,
I use realm join with a kerberos token generated before the join,
it's working fine on a simple Active Directory Configuration
My issue is when realm join must join a domain with a kerberos token from a cross domain authentication mechanism

Let's say I have two domains:
A.grp and B.com
there is a trust relationship between A and B (the users in A can be authenticated within the B domain)
which would be in krb5.conf something like this:

```
[realms]
A.GRP ={
        kdc = DC01.A.GRP
        kdc = DC02.A.GRP
        default_domain = a.grp
        admin_server = DC01.A.GRP
}
B.COM = {
  kdc = DC01.B.COM
  default_domain = B.COM
  admin_server = DC01.B.COM
}
[capaths]
A.GRP = {
  B.COM
}
```

The kerberos token is created for a user admin@a.grp
And the join is on B.COM like :

```
 join b.com
```

but realm create it's own krb5.conf that only point out to B.COM that trigger this kind of error :

```
Wrote out krb5.conf snippet to /var/cache/realmd/adcli-krb5-g6wFw4/krb5.d/adcli-krb5-conf-kJS7Pm
! Couldn't authenticate as machine account: MACHINE01: Client 'MACHINE01$@B.COM' not found in Kerberos database
```

How could I tell realm to use a cross domain authentication?